# simplesamplephp sp + idp set up issue

Tags: saml-2.0, service-provider

I am running two simplesamplephp instances (one for SP and one for IdP) and playing around with SSO. My IdP uses openLDAP for authorization.

I started from the following php code by putting them in an example.php file, put the example.php file in apache httpd and visit it from browser:

```
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('example-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attr = $as->getAttributes();
print ………..
```

It appears that the authentication request was able to be sent from sp to Idp and here is the sp log:

```
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] Session: 'example-sp' not valid because we are not authenticated.
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] Saved state: '_04c9e1a8c58932ab2d79c179a90d4e9c88e9c693f3'
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] Sending SAML 2 AuthnRequest to 'https://idp.example.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php'
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] Sending message:
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] <samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_04c9e1a8c58932ab2d79c179a90d4e9c88e9c693f3" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-07-06T19:56:06Z" Destination="https://idp.example.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sp.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/example-sp" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST">
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76]   <saml:Issuer>example-sp-host</saml:Issuer>
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76]   <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/>
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Then in the Idp log I see the following (appears that IdP was able to receive the request):

```
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp INFO [37f32bab7b] SAML2.0 - IdP.SSOService: Accessing SAML 2.0 IdP endpoint SSOService
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [37f32bab7b] Received message:
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [37f32bab7b] <samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_04c9e1a8c58932ab2d79c179a90d4e9c88e9c693f3" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-07-06T19:56:06Z" Destination="https://idp.example.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sp.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/example-sp" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST">
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [37f32bab7b]   <saml:Issuer>example-sp-host</saml:Issuer>
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [37f32bab7b]   <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/>
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [37f32bab7b] </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Then in the sp log I see the following:

```
Jul 06 19:56:06 simplesamlphp DEBUG [a08a5cff76] Redirect to 636 byte URL: https://idp.example.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?SAMLRequest=fVLfb4IwEP5XSN8RRKfQAInTLDNxk4jbw16WWs7RBFrWK%2Fvx36%2BAi%2B5hJs1dcnff912%2FNkZWVw1dtKaUO3hvAY3zVVcSad9ISKslVQwFUslqQGo4zRcPGxqMfNpoZRRXFbmAXEcwRNBGKEmc9Sohr%2F6URzBmIb8Jo0nADkExj%2Fh4HrHIL6YQ8TC0YRZNjhPiPINGi0yIJbJwxBbWEg2Txpb88cT15%2FbsfZ%2BOZzQIX4izsrcRkpkeVRrTIPU8UTQjKHWp0Iy4qj0UdVNBt7rXhaAb8PJ8m4P%2BEBxGTdkQZ%2FG791JJbGvQp%2B7TbnNmxn%2BJa1W0VU%2FlDUJDDlzGsa%2BecC5arezk6q2QhZBv1w09DENI7%2Ff7zM22%2BZ6kccdNe4N0emZ2uxx7l814eP1HS7teZaoS%2FNu5U7pm5rpqVxGFe%2BxHqdFMogBprE9VpT6XGpiBhBjdAvHSQfLvH0t%2FAA%3D%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fsp.example.com%2Fexample.php
```

But in my browser I got the following error:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving https://idp.example.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?SAMLRequest=fVLfb4IwEP5XSN8RRKfQAInTLDNxk4jbw16WWs7RBFrWK%2Fvx36%2BAi%2B5hJs1dcnff912%2FNkZWVw1dtKaUO3hvAY3zVVcSad9ISKslVQwFUslqQGo4zRcPGxqMfNpoZRRXFbmAXEcwRNBGKEmc9Sohr%2F6URzBmIb8Jo0nADkExj%2Fh4HrHIL6YQ8TC0YRZNjhPiPINGi0yIJbJwxBbWEg2Txpb88cT15%2FbsfZ%2BOZzQIX4izsrcRkpkeVRrTIPU8UTQjKHWp0Iy4qj0UdVNBt7rXhaAb8PJ8m4P%2BEBxGTdkQZ%2FG791JJbGvQp%2B7TbnNmxn%2BJa1W0VU%2FlDUJDDlzGsa%2BecC5arezk6q2QhZBv1w09DENI7%2Ff7zM22%2BZ6kccdNe4N0emZ2uxx7l814eP1HS7teZaoS%2FNu5U7pm5rpqVxGFe%2BxHqdFMogBprE9VpT6XGpiBhBjdAvHSQfLvH0t%2FAA%3D%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fsp.example.com%2Fexample.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

Note 1 - I am not sure why in the sp log it said "Session: 'example-sp' not valid because we are not authenticated". Maybe at that point the security context hasn't been established yet and that 's exactly why we need to execute $as->requireAuth() for?

Note 2 - What does the error in browser indicate? Does it mean I have to set up some additional html file or form to enter user name / password for LDAP validation? Any clues on how to set things up?

Note 3 - I followed most of the config changes according to the simplesamlphp SP and IdP guides except that I didn't change the 'certFingerprint' value. Will that possibly be the issue? I have copies of goDaddy.com signed SSLs for my IdP and SP - should I use them?

I actually expects SSOService.php to direct sp to loginuserpass.php but not sure why it didn't. I am thinking I may miss a setup somewhere but not sure exactly where...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I have a typo in the configuration file saml20-sp-remote.php that causes this issue. Once it is fixed I am being directed to the Idp login screen. Now just need to keep going!